React Native WebView whitescreen for both ios and android BUG
I am trying to implement this ballerine KYC web ui sdk into my react native app, and load it with react-native-webview. The html works perfectly fine on a regular index.html file but just produces a whitescreen for my react native project.
React native code:
import React from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";
import styled from "styled-components";
  
export const IDScanner = () => {
  const htmlContent = `
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <title>My KYC Flow</title>
        <script
        crossorigin
         src="https://cdn.ballerine.io/js/1.3.0/ballerine-sdk.umd.js"
         ></script>
       </head>
       <body>
        <div id="kyc-host">
        </div>
        <script>
        const ballerineInitConfig = {
        endUserInfo: {
          id: "test-id",
        },
        uiConfig: {
          uiPack: "default",
           flows: {
            "my-kyc-flow": {
              steps: [
                { name: "welcome", id: "welcome" },
                { name: "document-selection", id: "document-selection" },
                { name: "document-photo", id: "document-photo" },
                { name: "selfie", id: "selfie" },
                { name: "final", id: "final" },
              ],
            },
          },
        },
      };
        BallerineSDK.flows.init(ballerineInitConfig).then(() => {
         BallerineSDK.flows.openModal("my-kyc-flow", {});
         });
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>`;

  return (
    <View>
      <WebView
        originWhitelist={["*"]}
        source={{
          html: htmlContent,
        }}
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
      />
    </Container>

  );
};

You can also take the block of html and put it into an index.html to see an expected result.
